# Securing a multilayer browser game by re-running player's actions on the sever

Tags: node.js, security, dom, client, server

I am looking for a solution to prevent client-side hacks in a browser multiplayer turn-based card game. It is quite simple graphically so it is DOM based and not canvas/SVG. (Node.js back-end)

The problem is that every data sent from the client, about player's actions can be hacked at the client by simply manipulating JS. I could not think of a good way around it (except for maybe a key that changes every second, but that will put a huge load on the server.)

The solution I thought of was this: to have a copy of the HTML board at the server and each time a player submits a turn, have it re-run on the server where it can't be altered, and thus see that the player could actually do all the actions he/she submitted.

So my questions are:

- Could I be missing a simpler solution? (I don't think any kind of encryption would help me here since the actions can be manipulated *before* they are sent out.)
- How bad would be the server load? How expansive are DOM manipulations with Node and if (hopefully: ) I'll have a million players, would this still be a viable solution?

---

Update - the game logic:

The game is like chess with abilities. Each player has a turn, he can move his cards to other locations and fight other cards at those locations.

Each turn is isolated - it influences the other player in a way he can not prevent in his turn, and thus his response to a turn is not required.

So the player makes some actions and submits them. The actions might influence the other player too and if they do, his cards also change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Very likely. You are not giving details of the game's logic. Input validation is depends on what sort of game that is.
2. DOM manipulation is an overkill. Even if you want to emulate the *client* on the *server*, it shall be possible to do so without DOM.

Could you briefly explain us what is the game logic?

---

P.S. Time sensitive key will not overload server if it is done right.

But you have to always assume client will be able to crack through the front-end (there was no single software which was not cracked granted it is popular enough)

Comment: I made an update with the game logic. How would you suggest to secure such game?

Comment: Why do you need  DOM on the server? You could let the server remember the state of a game of each currently connected client. And once he submits an action, verify whether it is applicable to the current state. That is a common solution in online browser games.

Comment: You are right. Could you give an example of a a time-stamp-key done right?

Comment: Sorry got no examples. I just saw it being used in few games, know it is possible, but had no chance to peek into the actual implementation.